# Software definable battery controller to be able to re-use various laptop batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, laptop, reuse

I'm looking to retro-fit an older small netbook Toshiba NB100, by replacing the logic board with the single core Atom 1.6Ghz with an [up-board core](http://www.up-board.org/upcore/).

A hardware/software solution for re-using the battery for this laptop seems to be among the hardest task. Ideally I'm looking for some kind of programmable battery controller whereby the a particular battery can be defined in software.

I'd want to be able to charge while using the machine. I'd want battery level to be reported in the usual Windows way (ACPI drivers would be needed).

I think that there might be a good market for the upboard for re-using most of the parts of old laptops in this way: environmental particularly.

Related question, but appears to be specific to another battery: [Battery charging for DIY laptop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260512/battery-charging-for-diy-laptop)

Comment: *I think that there might be a good market for...* I would disagree as it will be almost impossible to make a board with a size that will fit in most laptops. For example there are many variations on the display connector. Even when they're electrically the same (like LVDS) there will be physical differences. Only hobbyists can/are willing to spend time on converting an old laptop like this. Few have the soldering skills required. The battery is only **one** of the challenging tasks to make your project a success.

Comment: you can go to TI or NXP's website and search for power management or battery management. There are tons of them for devices and batteries of various sizes.